# A basic and confusing question about command java -classpath using

Tags: java, command, classpath

When i using command java in git bash in windows,
Why is "java -cp .:./lib.jar main" different from "java -cp ./lib.jar:. main"?
Only the second command works right,and showing "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" after excute first command expression.
Is it that I don't understand how "-cp" works?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you don't know how `-cp` works, it's that you don't know that the syntax is `-cp .:./lib.jar main` on *NIX systems, and `-cp .;./lib.jar main` on Windows.

Colon for separation on *nix, semi-colon on Windows.